# Facebook fetching incorrect image [OG tags]

Tags: php, facebook

I've put correct og tags for images even here on this link https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ when I click on "Fetch new scrape information" and put url : http://quizistan.com/quizzes/can-you-answer-basic-core-php-question/36/r/ff351990-af7a-4dc7-905a-1cd12b9dbb45

It shows correct image in og:image of PHP which is correct but under "Based on included and inferred properties, the below preview is what users will see when they share this URL." it show image of mr. bean which is incorrect

what was the issue ? i am not able to get it please help thanks

Comment: You find the new tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and it say: "Provided og:image URL, http://quizistan.com/media/quiz/download%20(1).jpg was not valid because it did not meet the minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px."

Comment: thanks WizKid its working fine now :) please post it as answer so I can accept it :)